# Simplify CASE expression used multiple times

Tags: mysql

For readability, I would like to modify the below statement. Is there a way to extract the `CASE` statement, so I can use it multiple times without having to write it out every time?

```
select  
      mturk_worker.notes, 
      worker_id, 
      count(worker_id) answers, 
      count(episode_has_accepted_imdb_url) scored, 
      sum( case when isnull(imdb_url) and isnull(accepted_imdb_url) then 1 
                when imdb_url = accepted_imdb_url then 1 
                else 0 end ) correct, 
      100 * ( sum( case when isnull(imdb_url) and isnull(accepted_imdb_url) then 1 
                        when imdb_url = accepted_imdb_url then 1 
                        else 0 end) 
              / count(episode_has_accepted_imdb_url)  ) percentage
   from 
      mturk_completion 
         inner join mturk_worker using (worker_id) 
   where 
      timestamp > '2015-02-01' 
   group by 
      worker_id 
   order by 
      percentage desc, 
      correct desc
```

Comment: In order to achieve that, use the tsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually eliminate the `case` statements.  MySQL will interpret boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context (with 1 being true and 0 being false):

```
select mturk_worker.notes, worker_id, count(worker_id) answers, 
       count(episode_has_accepted_imdb_url) scored, 
       sum(imdb_url = accepted_imdb_url or imdb_url is null and accepted_idb_url is null) as correct, 
       (100 * sum(imdb_url = accepted_imdb_url or imdb_url is null and accepted_idb_url is null) / count(episode_has_accepted_imdb_url)
       ) as percentage
from mturk_completion inner join
     mturk_worker
     using (worker_id) 
where timestamp > '2015-02-01'
group by worker_id 
order by percentage desc, correct desc;
```

If you like, you can simplify it further by using the null-safe equals operator:

```
select mturk_worker.notes, worker_id, count(worker_id) answers, 
       count(episode_has_accepted_imdb_url) scored, 
       sum(imdb_url <=> accepted_imdb_url) as correct, 
       (100 * sum(imdb_url <=> accepted_imdb_url) / count(episode_has_accepted_imdb_url)
       ) as percentage
from mturk_completion inner join
     mturk_worker
     using (worker_id) 
where timestamp > '2015-02-01'
group by worker_id 
order by percentage desc, correct desc;
```

This isn't standard SQL, but it is perfectly fine in MySQL.

Otherwise, you would need to use a subquery, and there is additional overhead in MySQL associated with subqueries.

Comment: I guess the reason why I was using the case is to make sure "NULL = NULL". Would the second part of your answer accomplish that?

Comment: @Hockey127 . . . Yes, in MySQL `<=>` is a "null-safe" comparison operator.  So, if both values are `NULL`, then it returns true.